# Calculate the records for each calculations by month

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of count columns sent for each day, so I have to total those up for the entire month and then do the division to find the total count by month. how do I get the calculation of all three calculations by month

Below are the fields I'm trying to calculate, how do I total the records for the entire month:

```
CAST([Sid_Count] / NULLIF([Wrk_Count], 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS Quality_Field,
CAST([Talk_Count] / NULLIF([Sid_Count], 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS Utilization_Field,
CAST([Cell_Count] / NULLIF([Cell_No_Count] + Cell_No_Count, 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS Consent_Field
```

Example of what I'm trying to see: Calculation from Jan 8th to Feb 8th

```
DateByMonth      Quality_Field          Utilization_Field       Consent_Field           
2021-02-08       Total count by month   Total count by month    Total count by month
```

Comment: `GROUP BY EOMONTH(myDate)`?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected result. It will help us to understand your question better

Comment: Call_Date  Quality_Field  Utilization_Field   Consent_Field
2020-02-10  NULL          0.0000                 0.0000
2020-02-10  NULL          0.0000                 2.0000
2020-02-11  NULL          0.0000                 NULL
2020-02-11  NULL          0.0000                 NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @derivedDateStart DATE = '1/1/2015' --Set as far back as needed
DECLARE @derivedDateEnd DATE = getdate()
CREATE TABLE #tempDerivedMonth (tYear int, tMonth int)
WHILE @derivedDateStart < @derivedDateEnd
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempDerivedMonth(tYear, tMonth)
        SELECT YEAR(@derivedDateStart, MONTH(@derivedDateStart))

        SET DATEADD(m,1,@derivedDateStart)    
    END

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(myDate))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DAY(getdate()))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(myDate))),23)  AS DateByMonth,
SUM(CAST([Sid_Count] / NULLIF([Wrk_Count], 0) AS DECIMAL(18, 4))) AS Quality_Field,
SUM(CAST([Talk_Count]  / NULLIF([Sid_Count], 0)  AS DECIMAL(18, 4))) AS Utilization_Field,
SUM(CAST([Cell_Count] / NULLIF([Cell_No_Count] + Cell_No_Count, 0))  AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS Consent_Field
FROM YourTable yt
JOIN #tempDerivedMonth tdm
  ON tdm.tMonth = MONTH(myDate) AND tdm.tYear = YEAR(myDate) AND DAY(myDate) BETWEEN DAY(getdate()) and DATEADD(d,1,DATEADD(m,-1,getdate()))
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(myDate))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DAY(getdate()))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(myDate))),23)
```

Assuming you have a date column named myDate your solution might look something like this (messier than I'd like).  To group by a derived month I think you'll need a calendar table, which is #tempDerivedMonth in example.  Summing your equations allows you to Group output in your From Statement.  Curious to know if this works for you.  (thanks Rachel for the prompt to expand on initial answer)

Comment: Please add an explanation regarding why the above may work. this will improve the quality of your answer